# How to use time.sleep in an if statement and not stop the rest of the script

Tags: python

I have a python script that uses a while true and continues to run. In the while loop I have several if statements. Some of the if statements have a `time.sleep` in them. After using this for a while I notice that all of the if statements below the first `time.sleep` are waiting.

Is there way to have the if statements below the first `time.sleep` to run or will they always wait?

I could put all the if statements with the `time.sleep` on the bottom so all the if statements without a `time.sleep` get executed first. Unless there is another way I will try to build this on the fly script that way if I can.

```
while True:
   temp1 = tempRead1()

   if temp1 < 65:
      GPIO.output(17, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(17, True)
   if temp1 > 70 and GPIO.input(17):
      time.sleep(120)
      GPIO.output(27, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(27, True)
   if temp1 > 72 and GPIO.input(17):
      time.sleep(120)
      GPIO.output(22, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(22, True)
   if temp1 > 80 and GPIO.input(17):
      time.sleep(120)
      GPIO.output(5, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(5, True)
   if temp1 < 55:
      GPIO.output(6, False)
   else:
      GPIO.output(6, True)

time.sleep(60)
```

Comment: `time.sleep` pauses your program.  That includes all your code.  If you want to have multiple things happening simultaneously (like one part sleeping while another part does stuff) you'll need to look into threading or multiprocessing.

Comment: ...or just keep checking the current time at the top of the `while` loop and use that to decide when your outputs should go through.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds from your description that you want each if/else to execute simultaneously in parallel? As is, even if you reorder the statements, calling sleep will sleep the current thread, and since your program is single threaded, execution will stop for the specified time before continuing (meaning the executed if will sleep before evaluating the next if/else statement).

Rather than worrying about true simultaneous execution however, why don't you reorganize your if/elses to drop down to only a single sleep statement. Here is some shell code to get you started.

```
   if not GPIO.input(17) :
      # not going to sleep, add relevant if checks here
      ...

   else:
      # do all the if checks
      sleep = temp1 > 72 or temp1 ..... etc
      sleeping = [temp1 > 72, temp1 > ...]

      if sleep:
          time.sleep(120)
      #ok, now drive GPIO outs
      if sleeping[0]:
          GPIO.output(22, False)
      else:
          GPIO.output(22, True)
      ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is that you can't without using some form of threaded code, for your purposes in this script, in the `if...statements` simply define a variable for the sleep period and then  at the bottom of the loop,

```
if sleep_time != 0:
    time.sleep(sleep_time)
```